# Dust: How to check if an array which is passed to a dust file contains a certain element or not using dust helpers?

Tags: node.js, dust.js

```
res.render('home',o);
o={
   name:"Free Lunch",
   privilege:[3,4],
   const:{
          RESET:1,
          ADD:2,
          DELETE:3
          MANAGE:4,
          REPORT:5
           }
}
```

I want to check if dust-helper if condition whether the value corresponding to REPORT which is 5 is present in the privilege array or not.
<@if cond="......">

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the array and test each element but I can't think how you could use/store the fact after the iteration. I don't know a way to do this with the current language facilities but that is why custom dust helpers are provided. You could build a {@arrayContains key=array value=value} sort of helper. Since you don't say what you want to do once you determine the existence/non-existence, it is unclear what else the helper might do after the check.

Answer (score 0):

```
{@if cond="('{con.REPORT}' && '{con.REPORT}'.length)"}I EXIST DO SOMETHING{/if}
```

Before you test, make sure to add a , after the DELETE attribute